# Facing problems in copying files of type *.txt and *.xls in one folder to other folder using ruby script?

Tags: ruby

I am facing problems in copying of files from one location to other.

For example, there are folders starting from 1 to 6.
First time i wanted to copy *.txt and *.xls file present in folder 1 to
the PWD and do some other stuff and then followed by all the other
folders. for this initially i have copied all the folders path into a
read.txt files and the trying to iterate folder by folder. its fine in
this approach but if the txt file name changes then i can't able to do
that. The logic i am using is below:

```
require 'csv'
require 'fileutils'

dest_folder = File.join(Dir.pwd)

CSV.foreach("read.txt") do |row|        # read.txt contains the path
where xls and txt files are available.
  data_to =  "#{row}"
  concat = File.join(data_to)

  Source1 = File.join(concat, "file1.txt")
  Source2 = File.join(concat, "file2.xls")

  FileUtils.cp_r(Source1, dest_folder)
  FileUtils.cp_r(Source2, dest_folder)
  sleep 3
  puts "I am at end"
end
```

currently i am sending file names all the time. I wanted to get rid of
this. I wanted to implement in such a way that what ever the file name
ends with *.txt i should be able to copy?
Please let me know what improvement i can do to the current ruby script
such that i can copy file one by one and do my job.

Comment: this isn't related to the question but `Source1 =` seems really odd. why are you using a constant rather than a local variable like with `data_to`? also `File.join(Dir.pwd)` is totally redundant. It's exactly the same as doing just `Dir.pwd`. You only need to use `File.join()` if there are multiple arguments to join together. Same thing with `concat` further down. You could just do `source1 = File.join(row, "file1.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Dir::glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) to find all files of a certain type in a directory. For example, `Dir.glob["path/to/dir/*.txt"]` will return an array of all the files in `"path/to/dir"` that end in `.txt`. You can also use other shell globbing techniques to find more than one type of thing. With that in mind, you could rewrite your code like this:

```
CSV.foreach("read.txt") do |row|
  # find all files ending in .txt or .xls
  files = Dir.glob("#{row}/*.{txt,xls}")

  files.each do |file|
    FileUtils.cp_r(file, dest_folder)
  end
end
```